# Trying to cast an integer to a char

Tags: c++, c, debugging, casting, c++17

So I am trying to do a code that will work as a cypher. It will take in the word to cypher as input and output (print) the coded word. The problematic snippet of my code is the for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
   
        char input[] = "hello";
        printf("hello\n");
        printf("ciphertext: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        { 
            if(isalpha(input[i]))
            {
                int current = input[i];
                int cypher = ((current + 1) % 26 )+current;
                char out = (char)cypher;
                printf("%c", out);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", input[i]);
            }

        }
        printf("\n");
        
}
```

The problem that I run into when debugging is that the value  that ends up being stored in "out" seems correct, however whn it comes to printing it, it shows somehthing else entirely. I did look up quite a few things that I found on here , such as writing the code as such:

```
char out = (char)cypher;
```

```
char out= cypher + '0';
```

and so on but to no avail. The output should be ifmmp but rather i get j~rrx

Anything would help! thanks :)

Comment: `105 'i'` That's just the way the debugger displays the value stored in `out`, which is `105`. Since it's a `char` variable it adds the [ASCII representation](http://www.asciitable.com/) `i` but that's informational only.

Comment: sounds like you are confused by the output of the debugger. showing you that out contains decimal 108, hex 0x6c or ascii 'l', these are all different interpretations of the same single byte. See http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: In your example, it would be helpful to know what `i` in `int current = input[i];` is... [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It is inside a for loop , I have updated it

Comment: @pm100 I understand that now , thank you. However it is still not displaying the right letter

Comment: this code will output 5 characters, what one is wrong?

Comment: @seaiam The code in the question (a) doesn't compile, and (b) doesn't output a `d` after the missing `;` and headers are added. Please post *real* code. Copy/paste, do not retype.

Comment: @pm100 all five , the output i get is j~rrx , however when i debug my "out" variable seems to always be storing the correct value

Comment: Post your debugger value and actual display should help. Note that debugger might display in decimal or hex by its setting.

Comment: @LouisGo i just updated my question. Thank you !

Comment: If you managed to solve the problem yourself, remove "solved" from the title and consider posting an answer to your own question.

Comment: Btw I tested your code and output is "i}qqw". https://godbolt.org/z/hzrbsq. Also your code seems like pure C, C++ tags should be removed.

Comment: Perform mod relative to `'a'`: `char out = (input[i] - 'a' + 1)%26 + 'a';` for lowercase `input[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the correct answer. 105 is the ASCII value 'i'. There is no difference. More precisely, the `char` type is defined as an integer. On virtually all compilers it is 8 bits in size. So an `unsigned char` can have a value between 0 and 255; a signed `char` can have a value between -128 and +127.

So when your `out` variable has the value 105, it has the value 'i'.

The output of your `printf` will be:

```
i
```

But if you look at the `out` variable in a debugger, you might see `105`, depending on the debugger.

Comment: yes i understand that. However the output I have been getting is j~rrx even though my "out" variable seems to be storig the right value